# Sound and vibration with FCM notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications for my iOS app. I would like to add a vibration and sound when the device receives a notification. I've tried the following structure for the message:

```
var message = {

            "notification": {
              "title":"Ma Cherie",
              "body":messageText
            },
            "sound":"default"
            topic: topic
  };
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error sending message: { Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "sound" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.
```

I have also tried:

```
var message = {

            "notification": {
              "title":"Ma Cherie",
              "body":messageText
            },
            "apns": {
                 "payload": {
                     "aps": {
                        "sound": "default"
                     }
                 }
            },
            topic: topic
  };
```

but I get the same error. How do I add a sound to the notification (and a vibration and badge)?

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
 "sound":"default"
```

with

```
"ios": { "notification": { "sound": 'default' } }
```

I had similar issue on android and this worked for me.
Please refer to [Jaime's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241417) for details.

Comment: The linked post literally says what he does already.